# When to use BindingAdapter and when to use liveData or observable field in MVVM?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I am confused about the best way to use these patterns, for example where is the best place to validate `EditText` text? in the activity or `ViewModel` using `observable` field or using `bindingAdapter`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about validating whether the text input is Correct or Incorrect, **that's Logic and should be handled in the ViewModel**, where input changes can be observed and then depending on whether they are Correct or Incorrect, something happens (like RED underscore or Green check mark or something else).

The **BindingAdapter** should simply be used to *transform* something into something else.
For example: Boolean variable -> Strings TRUE or FALSE.

Example of ViewModel Logic for text input:

```
val textInput = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()
val inputCorrect: LiveData<Boolean>

textInput
    .switchMap { input -> textCorrect(input) }
    .subscribe( inputCorrect.postValue(it) )
```